# why does opening 2 instances of VS2022 cause compile errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have 2 sets of projects that have their own solutions.  Here is the problem I am running into as well along with a couple of other teammates.

I open VS2022 and load solution A.  I clean and rebuild it with no errors.
I open another instance of VS2022 and load solution B.  I clean and rebuild it with no errors.

I go back to the other instance of VS2022 with solution A and try to rebuild it... multiple errors now.  I have to close the solution and that instance of VS2022.  Reopen VS2022 and reload solution A and now solution A will rebuild with no issues.

Has anyone else other than me and a couple of my teammates had this issue and does anyone know why this might be happening and how to correct it?

thanks!

Comment: What are the errors? Are they sharing any project references between the two solutions?

Comment: they are not sharing any common references/libs as they are 2 totally stand alone projects.  The error are numerous .... system reference errors and the like.  as I mentioned closing the solution and instance of vs and then reopening it ... then compiles fine.